# Count items in Phoenix's Presence in constant time

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Phoenix with LiveView and I have this code in one of my views.

The part where I update the socket to include the

```
      def handle_info(%{event: "presence_diff", payload: _payload}, socket) do
 
        # (Payload handling omitted... I just want the count)

        users_count = map_size(Presence.list("some_topic"))

        {:noreply, assign(socket, :users_count, users_count}
      end
```

According to the documentation of `map_size`, "This operation happens in constant time.", so no problem here, but what about the return of `Presence.list` (which returns a `Map` by the way, not a `List`).

Is this list created from scratch every time I call `Presence.list`? Or just some kind of reference?

I'm concerned if I have N = 10,000 users, then every time someone joins/leaves, the list has to be created N times (one for each user), and each list containing N items. That'd be a waste of resources. Also, the `Presence` module doesn't seem to have any direct function to get the count.

I did read a lot of the source code, but couldn't get to any real conclusion.

Note: I know in the presence map, each key has an array of `metas`, but I'm only interested in the amount of different keys.